# load watcher runs on default port 2020 don't work

Tags: api, kubernetes, deployment, service, metrics-server

i am trying to deploy an image and associated with a service (NodePort), i just create the image and try to use a specific port 2020 like it say here: [image]

but i still having problem , did any one can explain to me haw to do it ?  i use Kubernetes metrics server and it's running BTW.
here the repository am using so you could understand the big picture

so GET/WATCHER don't return any think wen i run it in my terminal

and i create the image and then run the pod and it's working but the logs show this error :

`time="2022-09-18T15:44:09Z" level=error msg="received error while fetching metrics: Get \"https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes\": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host" func="github.com/paypal/load-watcher/pkg/watcher.(*Watcher).StartWatching.func1" file="/go/src/github.com/paypal/load-watcher/pkg/watcher/watcher.go:131"`

so to sum up i would like to deploy the load-watcher as a service and see the result on the port 2020 like he say or any other port.
thanks again.

Comment: Can you post the output received for command : GET /watcher and also post the error you are facing for better resolution.

Comment: the out put of GET /watcher is empty and i will modified the question to present the error. hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

The GET /watcher is empty, It might be due to two possibilities:

Please try to trouble shoot this by changing the network plugin from calico to canal or try as mentioned this [Gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/212#issuecomment-459321884).

Another Possibility is :

Metrics server may fail to authenticate if kubelet is running with `--anonymous-auth=false` flag.
Passing `--authentication-token-webhook=true` and `--authorization-mode=Webhook` flags to kubelet can fix this.

kops config for kubelet:

```
kubelet:

  anonymousAuth: false

  authenticationTokenWebhook: true

  authorizationMode: Webhook
```

This might break authorization for kubelet-api user if `ClusterRoleBinding` is not created with `system:kubelet-api-admin`. Which can be fixed by creating the ClusterRoleBinding:

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1

metadata:

  name: kubelet-api-admin

subjects:

- kind: User

  name: kubelet-api

  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

roleRef:

  kind: ClusterRole

  name: system:kubelet-api-admin

  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```